# ggsave with non-ASCII plotmath labels using cairo

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I have a non-ASCII axis label with a plotmath expression.  When I try to save as png using cairo, I get an error:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggsave("test.png",
       qplot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl) +
         ylab(expression(`cÜl`~italic(r)(italic(M)))) +
         xlab(expression(hp~italic(hp))),
       device = grDevices::png,
       type = "cairo")
```

The error message is:

```
Metric information not available for this family/device
```

On the other hand, using the "windows" device works (except for a warning):

```r
ggsave("test.png",
       qplot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl) +
         ylab(expression(`cÜl`~italic(r)(italic(M)))) +
         xlab(expression(hp~italic(hp))),
       device = grDevices::png,
       type = "windows")
```

The warning (in German) is:

```
In dev(filename = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) :
  'width=7, height=7' sind unwahrscheinliche Pixelzahlen
```

Finally, non-ASCII axis labels are not a problem per se, if the label is not a plotmath expression:

```r
ggsave("test.png",
       qplot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl) +
         ylab("cÜl") +
         xlab(expression(hp~italic(hp))),
       device = grDevices::png,
       type = "cairo")
```

The last command raises no error.

However, I would prefer to use cairo, since it draws nicer pictures sometimes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked on a Windows machine with R 4.0.2 (and also on linux):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggsave("test.png", width = 6, height = 6,
       qplot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl) +
           labs(x = "hp *hp*",
                y = "c\u00DCl *r*(*M*)") +
           theme(
               axis.title.x = element_markdown(),
               axis.title.y = element_markdown()
           ),
       type = "cairo-png")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (though I am not on windows); try leaving out the `device` parameter:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggsave("test.png",
       qplot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl) +
           ylab(expression(`cÜl`~italic(r)(italic(M)))) +
           xlab(expression(hp~italic(hp))),
       type = "cairo-png")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: No, that does not work either.  If the `device` parameter is not set, it is determined automatically.  If the filename ends with ".png", it leads to `device = grDevices::png`, I guess.

Comment: If you are willing to use an additional package, you could try the edited version, using `ggtext`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try `ggtext`.  Since your "edit" is actually a second answer, please post it as a second answer.  If there is no other answer, I will mark it as accepted.